# is there a css frameworks that allows to set height of div 100% of parent?

Tags: html, height, css-frameworks

is there a css frameworks that allows to set height of div 100% of parent?

I don't see why it's not implemented in CSS in the firstplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented in CSS.  You do `height: 100%`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCPYV/) that shows it in action.

Comment: it doens't work if parent's height is specified by height of the sibling http://jsfiddle.net/SCPYV/1/

Comment: On the other hand, that is an acceptable solution. Thanks! ;)